# FirefoxDriver fails to start : blocklist is disabled

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, playframework, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using `playframework 2.3` and I have an error when I use the Firefox Driver :

> [error] *** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
>   [error]
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
>   [error]
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
>   [

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading selenium seems to fix :

`libraryDependencies += "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.44.0"`